# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM

Tags: android, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo una aplicación Android que envía constantemente varios datos a mi servidor, necesito que estos datos se estén enviando de manera constante a lo largo del día, sin embargo, el envío de los datos dura aproximadamente una hora y después la aplicación se cierra y me muestra este error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM
```

Intenté lo que indican en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio) de agregar en el manifest `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`  y  `android:largeHeap="true"` pero la app se me sigue cerrando.

Esta es la parte del código donde proceso las cadenas que recibo por bluetooth y que envió a mi servidor para que inserte los datos en mi BD.

```
private Handler mMainHandler = new Handler()
{

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {

        case CONST.MSG_LEER:
            String readMessage =  msg.obj.toString();
            int charInicioCadena = readMessage.indexOf("#");
            int charInicioTiempo = readMessage.indexOf("{");
            int charInicioValor = readMessage.indexOf("(");
            int charInicioValor2 = readMessage.indexOf(")");
            int charFinCadena = readMessage.indexOf("~");//#lab{10000(~


            if (charFinCadena > 0) {
                try {
                    nombreDispositivo = readMessage.substring(charInicioCadena + 1, charInicioTiempo);

                switch (nombreDispositivo) {

                    case "ecg":
                        cuenta++;
                        segundo = readMessage.substring(charInicioTiempo + 1, charInicioValor);
                        valorECG = readMessage.substring(charInicioValor + 1, charFinCadena);//Valor ECG de tipo cadena
                        ecgValuefloat = Float.parseFloat(valorECG);
                        //checar minimo y maximo cada entrada

                        if(ecgValuefloat<Globals.valorMinimo){Globals.valorMinimo=ecgValuefloat;}
                        if(ecgValuefloat>Globals.valorMaximo) {Globals.valorMaximo=ecgValuefloat;}

                        if(Globals.envio_permitido==1) {
                            Globals.lstPromedios.add(ecgValuefloat);
                            Globals.lstTiempoPromedio.add(Integer.parseInt(segundo));
                            Globals.lstSendContadorECG.add(cuenta);

                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    ServiceManager2.onSendData();
                                }
                            },257);//Tiempo de retardo para empezar a enviar datos.
                        }
                        MainActivity.mECGWaveDraw.add(Integer.parseInt(valorECG));
                        break;
```

Esto es lo que me marca en android studio:

```
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 112MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 96MB/96MB, paused 22.089ms total 294.317ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.477s for cause Alloc
I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 96MB/96MB, paused 1.410ms total 10.915ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.335s for cause HeapTrim
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.596ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 1.922s for cause Alloc
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 112MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 96MB/96MB, paused 1.423ms total 291.358ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 1.906s for cause Alloc
E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM" (recursive case)
E/art: "pool-1-thread-5" prio=5 tid=24 Runnable
E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c08880 self=0xb7fee030
E/art:   | sysTid=31189 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb8061450
E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1033 stm=151 core=1 HZ=100
E/art:   | stack=0xa23b3000-0xa23b5000 stackSize=1036KB
E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
E/art:     at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:105)
E/art:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.getResponseData(unavailable:-1)
E/art:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(unavailable:-1)
E/art:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(unavailable:-1)
E/art:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(unavailable:-1)
E/art:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(unavailable:-1)
E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/art:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/art:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 112MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1(16B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 96MB/96MB, paused 1.317ms total 294.517ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.157s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 249.580ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.680ms
E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM" (recursive case)
E/art: "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x73007000 self=0xb7bce6d0
E/art:   | sysTid=27944 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f19bec
E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4883 stm=1409 core=1 HZ=100
E/art:   | stack=0xbe217000-0xbe219000 stackSize=8MB
E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
E/art:     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
E/art:     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
E/art:     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
E/art:     at com.botonmedico.amunet.service.ServiceManager2.onSendData(ServiceManager2.java:250)
E/art:     at com.botonmedico.amunet.MainActivity$3$1.run(MainActivity.java:454)
E/art:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/art:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/art:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/art:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
E/art:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
E/art:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/art:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
E/art:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 121(44KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 20.869ms total 279.848ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.170s for cause Alloc
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 1.851s for cause Alloc
E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
E/System: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM
              at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize(BinderInternal.java:51)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:191)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 114(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.284ms total 285.480ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.396s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 258.115ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 98(43KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 2.321ms total 290.789ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 4.416s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 244.202ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 215(47KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.444ms total 277.432ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.644s for cause Alloc
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 236(49KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.328ms total 308.473ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.953s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 265.711ms

       --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-593
                  Process: com.botonmedico.amunet, PID: 27944
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM
                      at com.botonmedico.amunet.wave.DrawRunnable.run(DrawRunnable.java:73)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 68(7KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 2.425ms total 298.383ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.682s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 350.898ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 23.158ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(448B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 25.036ms total 394.020ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 5.659s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 373.959ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9(2384B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 2.556ms total 425.551ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.218s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 331.176ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.698ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 197(48KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 23.694ms total 362.057ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.515s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.080ms
I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(2320B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 2.135ms total 14.007ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.544s for cause Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 308.457ms
W/IdleConnectionHandler: Removing a connection that never existed!
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: File too large to fit into available memory
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.getResponseData(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: File too large to fit into available memory
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.getResponseData(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 215(54KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 2.114ms total 347.611ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.583s for cause Alloc
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.041s for cause Alloc
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 19.112ms for cause Explicit
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 271.340ms
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27944 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver este problema? De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Sin añadir nada de codigo es virtualmente imposible saber que problema tienes. Seguramente es el fragmento donde envias esos datos pero como he dicho sin ver codigo nadie va a poder ayudarte.

Comment: Un poco de código y el tipo de dato que intentas transferir... imágenes, texto, documentos, pdf... ¿? Tratando de _adivinar_ el contexto de tu app puedo uno tener también el error  OutofMemory :) Saludos, y pronto habrá una solución, cuando des más detalles..

Comment: @Curro  Edité el post, agregue código donde hago el envío de los datos asi como el error que marca cuando se me cierra la app. Espero pueda ayudar a dar a entender mejor mi problema.
@A Lo que estoy enviando es solo texto

Comment: He estado mirando y la verdad es poco te puedo decir. Lo que tengo claro es que llego un punto en el que los datos en memoria se hacen tan grandes que se desborda la misma y te da ese error. La solucion que me viene a la cabeza ya la has probado y no te funciona (añadir al manifest unos valores) y sinceramente no se que mas puedo decirte. Esperemos que alguien con mas ideas pueda decir algo. Suerte.

Comment: @Curro Sabes lo que estoy pensando es que cuando envío los datos al servidor no me regresa una respuesta tan rápido como debería y por eso se me van encolando los datos lo que ocasiona que consuma memoria y termino por acabarse haciendo que la app se detenga.

Comment: @Xavi pues ahora que lo dices no es tan descabellada esa teoría, es mas, los tiros pueden ir por ahí muy fácilmente. Intenta meter todo el proceso en un asynctask de manera que envíes los datos y cuando tengas la respuesta entonces envíes los siguientes....

Comment: Con lo que muestras de código no es posible averiguar dónde tienes el problema de memoria. Si una parte de tu código no libera memoria (por ejemplo agregando caracteres de manera indefinida a un `String`) otras zonas del programa producirán errores de memoria por no tener espacio en el `heap`, pero lo que estás viendo en esos mensajes es el síntoma del problema, no el problema en sí. ¿Podrías mostrar todo el código relacionado con el flujo de recepción de datos? (por ejemplo lo que pasa en `ServiceManager2.onSendData()` podría estar también relacionado).

Comment: Veo bastante, por ejemplo, el uso de `Globals.lstXXX.add()`. ¿Tienes acotado el tamaño máximo de esas listas? Es decir, ¿implementas algún tipo de control de tamaño que permita eliminar los datos más antiguos para no saturar la memoria con el paso del tiempo?